# VS2015 Properly Targeting .Net Framework 4.6.1 with new Web Application Project or Class Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I've created a new Web Application Project in VS2015 using the newer aspnet5 templates.  However I can't seem to find a straight answer on how to specifically target the .NET 4.6.1 Framework with it.  Looking at the pictures below can someone please shed some light on how to use the newer prject structures but target the .NET Framework 4.6.1 with them.  According to microsoft this is possible but I can't make heads or tails on specifically how to do this.

The old and new ways are shown below.
The new way below shows use specific runtime...
[image]

With the following showing in the references
[image]

The old way seemed much more straight forward.  Showing a specifically targeted framework.

[image]

The same problem exist for Class Library projects where it seems to want to target an SDK vs a particular version of the framework.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817523/asp-net-5-project-not-properly-targeting-net-4-6-1-and-cannot-be-debugged

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set your `DNX_IIS_RUNTIME_FRAMEWORK` environment variable to "DNX461". I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671851/vs-2015-setting-right-target-framework-for-asp-net-5-web-project) relevant.

Comment: From what I've read DNX for framework identification is going away. After reading these two articles http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md

Comment: I tried this just for kicks and it didn't work... I set the project.json to dnx46 and that worked without the use of the environment variable.  But is Running on DNX46 the same as saying it's running on The .Net Framework 4.6 and not .NET Core v1.0

Comment: If you want to brute force it, you can edit your project's `.csproj` file with a text editor, locate the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` tag and set it manually there. Not an elegant solution, though...